# DB2 Insert Into Temp Table in the middle of a script

Tags: insert, db2, temp

If I have several temp tables, and I want to insert data into one of them but then continue to create more temp tables is there a way to do that or do I need to break my query up.

This is an example of what I'd like to do

```
WITH A AS (SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeConditionA), -- Inital Temp Table
B AS(SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeConditionB), --Second Temp Table
INSERT INTO A SELECT * FROM B --Insert Table B into Table A
C AS(...), --Derives From A
D AS(...), --Derives From C
E AS(...) --Derives From D
SELECT * FROM E --Final Select Statement
```

Essentially my issue is that I don't know how to write the insert in a way that will allow me to continue creating more temp tables afterwards.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Common Table Expression (CTE), `WITH A AS (SELECT...)` is not an actual temporary table, you can't insert into it.

It doesn't appear that you need to have a B since it's the same columns as selected in A, simply `OR` the conditions

```
WITH A AS (SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 
           FROM SomeTable 
          WHERE SomeConditionA 
             or SomeConditionB),
  C AS(...), --Derives From A
  D AS(...), --Derives From C
  E AS(...) --Derives From D
SELECT * FROM E --Final Select Statement
```

If B needed to select other columns or from another table, then `UNION ALL` (if duplicates are ok or not possible) or `UNION` (to remove any duplicate rows) the results.

```
WITH A AS (SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 
           FROM SomeTable 
          WHERE SomeConditionA 
            UNION ALL
          SELECT Column4, Column5, Column6 
           FROM SomeTable 
          WHERE SomeConditionB),
  C AS(...), --Derives From A
  D AS(...), --Derives From C
  E AS(...) --Derives From D
SELECT * FROM E --Final Select Statement
```

Comment: Thanks, the examples provided are much simpler than my actual query so the unions will not work, so the answer seems to be it cannot be done. I believe the solution then is to create multiple queries.

Comment: If the "insert" would have worked, then the union would also.

Comment: Okay let me try it actually.

Comment: Then have the union query transform them so they are compatible.... Same as you'd have had to do to insert them into A.